# html to excel with php. Big numbers converts to exponential

Tags: php, excel, number-formatting

I'm exporting `html` table to `excel` with `php`. I have a problem with column with big numbers

Example: `12345678901234567890`

Excel converts it to `1.23457E+19` in general format.

I want to get display the full number - completely.

Comment: Doesn't expanding the width of the column solve this?

Comment: change the format of the cell to text, may be that helps!

Comment: Expanding does not help

Comment: where is the problem? in php or in excell?

Comment: Share the php code here.

Comment: excel automatically converts number coloumns to floating point .. but I need the coloumn in text format only ..

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a single quote to numbers that have a length > 10-12. I have this same problem with a few part numbers.

VBA

```
bigNumber = "'" & bigNumber
```

or

PHP

```
$bigNumber = "'" . $bigNumber
```

My php is very rusty, you might have to escape the quote.